Generalised traceform
Let $k$ be a perfect field and $R$ a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra. The
trace form (,) : R × R → k defined via $(x, y) = Tr_{R/k}(xy) = Tr_R(mult_{xy})$ is
nondegenerate iff $R \cong k_1 \times · · · \times k_n$ where $k_1, . . . , k_n$ are finite (hence separable)
field extensions of $k$.
I have seen the case for $R$ a field but not sure about how this works when $R$ is an algebra. Does  anyone have a reference?

I guess that $R$ is supposed to be commutative, since otherwise this is false : $R=M_n(k)$ has a non degenerate trace form but is not a product of field extensions of $k$.
In the sequel, I will assume that $R$ is commutative.
Assume that the trace form is non degenerate.
Any nilpotent element of $R$ lies in the radical of the trace form: if $x$ is nilpotent, then for all $y$, $xy$ is nilpotent (since $R$ is commutative!) hence its trace is zero.
Thus, by assumption, $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements. But it is known that an unital associative finite dimensional $k$-algebra with no nonzero nilpotent elements is isomorphic to a direct product of field extensions (see for example the answer to this question: Characterize finite dimensional algebras without nilpotent elements)
